# How to install CSS templates with Flask?

Tags: python, css, flask

I'm trying to use this template: http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page185/flat-style#shout

and this is my file directory:

```
app
    - static
      [--] css (inside static)
      [--] images (inside static)
      [--] js (inside static)
    - templates
```

but the images won't load properly still: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVEtR.png

Does anyone know why the images won't properly load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simply dumped the HTML from the website in to your templates folder and all the href and src attributes for images and CSS are still using relative links. These need to be converted to use Flask's static files functionality.

For example, to get the CSS working, change this line:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

to this:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

And similarly for images, you can change:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" title="Flat style" />
```

to

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png') }}" title="Flat style" />
```

You'll need to do this for all static files referenced in the HTML.

Note that your Flask app will need to have imported `url_for`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man for the help. It took a while but after changing them all it worked!